# Highlighting color strings with correspondent color

Tags: syntax-highlighting, color

When tweaking color themes, one thing I really miss is a highlighting that
would color the color strings with the corresponding color.

Maybe this sounds confusing? An example: here is a fragment of a Vim theme:

```
hi Constant    ctermfg=Magenta      guifg=Magenta
hi Special     ctermfg=Red          guifg=Red
hi Identifier  ctermfg=Cyan         guifg=Green
```

I would like to have a syntax highlight that would color `Magenta` in magenta, `Red` in red, and so on,
similar to what happens with color codes for dircolors file:

[image: dircolors file displayed in Vim editor]

`01;34` is the color code for blue, thus Vim displays it in blue, `01;36` is cyan, etc.

I searched into the syntax directory for files with "color" in their name,

```
$ find . -iname '*color*'
./colortest.vim
./dircolors.vim
./syncolor.vim
```

but none of these do the job for the color strings.

Am I missing some resource or do I have to create my own syntax file?

Comment: This may not be what you want, but I find `:hi` helpful.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/gu-fan/colorv.vim. It has commands to preview colors in line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of plugins that do this for colour names, hex colours, and RGB colours:

- [Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) by Christian Brabandt, (who appears to be modestly refraining from answering this question with a link to his own plugin),
- [Coloresque](https://github.com/gko/vim-coloresque) by Konstantin,
- [vim-css-color](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color) by Aristotle Pagaltzis,
- [vim-css-color](https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color) (a different one) by Max Vasiliev